# Get command line current folder in ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm writing a small ruby gem which should generate couple of files, so I'm using executables.

How can I (in my ruby code) get the current folder of the command line from which the gem was executed?

For example, when I run my tool in this path:

```
~/Projects/MyProject/ $ my-tool
```

How can I get the `~/Projects/MyProject/` in my ruby code?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dir.pwd` or `Dir.getwd` should do. Please note they return full absolute path, with `~` expanded.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Dir.html#method-c-pwd

Comment: `File.dirname(__FILE__)` can be used for the relative path